# Merge/Combine two object arrays from different fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have an array ***in_cart*** which has *product_id*(s) and the *amount* of the individual items in the cart document

```
"in_cart":[
  {
    "product_id":"12345",
    "amount":2
  }  
]
```

What I want is to do is **insert** the *amount* field into the ***details*** array. **$lookup** operator is done on the product_id so there will always be an equal amount of items in both arrays.

```
"details":[
  {
    "_id":"12345",
    "name":"test",
    "price":1110,
    // ...more data...
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate over the **details** array.
- `$filter` to filter out the document from **in_cart** array that has the same value of **product_id** field as the current item from **details** array have in **_id** field
- `$arrayElemAt` to get the first element of the filtered array (since it will always have only one element)
- `$getField` to get only **amount** property of filtered item

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      details: {
        $map: {
          input: "$details",
          in: {
            _id: "$$this._id",
            name: "$$this.name",
            price: "$$this.price",
            amount: {
              $getField: {
                field: "amount",
                input: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$in_cart",
                        as: "cart_item",
                        cond: {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$cart_item.product_id",
                            "$$this._id"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JoP56TwZ27Z)